# Is it possible to return a value from the $emit?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component

I have a child component calling Parent using $emit. How can we get a return value back from the $emit ?

I tried to return a value as well as include a variable in the function and neither of them work. Is it the nature of the $emit function that can't return a value? Are there any workarounds ?

Child:

```
let data = null;

await this.$emit('loadData', this.Id, data);
```

Parent:

```
 async loadData(Id, data) {
 
    let newData = await this.$store.dispatch('user/loadUserData', Id);
   
    data = { ...newData };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return from `$emit`. Usually you mutate a parent's state on events emitted by its child. Then a child use the parent's state to update itself for example through props. That's how `v-model` works btw:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

If you want to get a value from a parent, just call its method:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Parent:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Comp from './Comp.vue';

const rows = ref([]);
const counter = ref(0);
defineExpose({getRow(){ return 'Row ' + ++counter.value}});

</script>

<template>
  <comp />
</template>
```

Child:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
const rows = ref([]);
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="row in rows">{{ row }}</div>
  <div>
    <button @click="rows.push($parent.getRow())" >Add row</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can also use provide/inject:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

You can emit arguments with the event. It is explained in the official [guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments). They have this example:

MyButton component:

```
<button @click="$emit('increaseBy', 1)">
  Increase by 1
</button>
```

Parent:

```
<MyButton @increase-by="increaseCount" />


function increaseCount(n) {
  count.value += n
}
```

They also state:

> All extra arguments passed to $emit() after the event name will be
> forwarded to the listener. For example, with $emit('foo', 1, 2, 3) the
> listener function will receive three arguments.